# Configure JUNIT5 correctly for Tests

Tags: java, spring, junit, configuration, junit5

I have few tests on my project and when I execute the whole test class I get `No tests were found` but when I test each method independently they still work and I figured out JUnit5 is not configured correctly. 
The following are my jars and pom.xml

[image]

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>...</name>
    <description>...</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <junit-platform.version>5.6.2</junit-platform.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.32</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;

@SpringBootTest
public class ApplicationTests {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    private static String BASE_PATH = "http://localhost:8080/exams/";

    @Test
    public void testNotFoundStartExamException() {
        final String url = BASE_PATH + "start/" + null + "/";

        assertThrows(HttpClientErrorException.class, () -> restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void testNotFoundFinishExamException() {
        final String url = BASE_PATH + "finish-page/" + null + "/";

        assertThrows(HttpClientErrorException.NotFound.class, () -> restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class));
    }
}
```

and when I use command `mvn test` it gives the following result

```
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  12.137 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-19T08:18:07+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am not sure what to use, why it does not work and how to make it work, according to documentation I need `jupiter-engine, platform-launcher, vintage-engine`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show your test class including imports. And your full pom.xml.

Comment: @johanneslink I edited it.

Comment: you have `spring-boot-starter-test` which already includes junit Jupiter dependency for you. what is the output you get when you run `mvn test`, can you share the output?

Comment: You have to add either the Surefire-Plugin or Faiilsafe plugin, I guess.

Comment: @Sachin I edited the post and it gives ```build success``` seems like it skips tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to duplicate/multiple junit dependency being added to pom.xml. As mentioned earlier you have `spring-boot-starter-test` which already includes junit Jupiter (`5.5.2` for `2.2.6.RELEASE` spring starter) dependency for you. You have manually added higher version of the junit (5.6.2).

[image]

If you take a look at the [Junit 5 User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/) it specifies `junit-jupiter-engine in test runtime scope` but since you have not specified any scope it goes to compile scope which you can verify it from checking the Effective Pom.

Simple way to fix is to remove the manually added junit dependency and run `mvn clean test`. your test should get picked